# How do I add characters to the ANSI terminal so that the user can move their cursor through them?

Tags: ansi-term, ansi

Specifically, I want to do something like this:

```
aaaaaaaa_
```

Where the cursor can move through the `a`s.

Comment: Have you looked at the curses library?

Comment: (1) At the shell prompt, type `aaaaaaaa`; do no press Enter. (2) You can now move the cursor backwards and forwards through the `a`s with the arrow keys. (3) I suspect that this is not what you wanted, but this is what you asked.

Comment: With Bash, you could `read -e -i aaaaaaaa`, and the user can use left and right or the usual control combinations to move among them.  Not sure what it's useful for, though.